# Upload image files to AWS S3 through DroneCI step

Tags: amazon-s3, drone.io

We have following steps in our DroneCI pipeline.

Step 1. Build Image and Push to ECR (using a ecr plugin)

That's it!!

Now, problem statement is that we need to copy few files before we push it to ECR. Like, if we have a file inside the codebase `/test/bundle_file/my_file.js`, then we need to copy this `my_file.js` and push it to AWS S3 bucket folder.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another step to your Drone pipeline. You can upload the files to S3 first and then publish the new Docker image. [Here are more details](https://stuff.21zoo.com/posts/drone.io-ecr-and-s3-pipeline-example/) but it should look something like this:

```yaml
steps:

...

  # Upload files to S3
  - name: upload files to s3
    image: plugins/s3
    settings:
      bucket: my-s3-bucket
      region: us-east-1
      source: /test/bundle_file/my_file.js
      target: /my_file.js
      access_key:
        from_secret: aws_access_key_id
      secret_key:
        from_secret: aws_secret_access_key 
             
  # Push Docker image to ECR
  - name: publish to ecr
    image: plugins/ecr
    settings:
      repo: your-aws-account-id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/your-repo
      region: us-west-2
      tags:
        - latest
        - "1.0.0"
      create_repository: true
      access_key:
        from_secret: aws_access_key_id
      secret_key:
        from_secret: aws_secret_access_key
```